# Submit form through ajax using verify.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, verify

How can I submit a form through AJAX while using verify.js? I want verify.js to only validate the login form:

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="login" action="auth/login" >
```

Comment: Have you tried annything yourself?

Comment: If you're asking about [the Verify plugin](http://verifyjs.com), it would be a good idea to use the [tag:verify] tag rather than the [tag:jquery-validate] tag which is a totally different plugin.  Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read any of [the documentation](http://verifyjs.com/#how-to-option) at all?  Looks like you would put your `ajax` inside the `beforeSubmit` option.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it's not really apparent that you would should hook into `beforeSubmit`, perform the AJAX request, and return `false`.

Comment: Thanks for reply now my question is how can we distinguish which form is submitted? Can we pass it of the form here?

Comment: Sparky can you answer my comments please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Sparky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28439237/369450#comment-45209227) pointed out, you can perform your AJAX request inside the `beforeSubmit` callback. To put that into prospective, you would do something similar to:

```
$('#login').verify({
    'beforeSubmit': function(form, result) {
        if (result) {
            // Since the form is valid, submit form via AJAX.
            $.ajax(...);
        }

        // Form is either invalid or was already submitted, return `false` to tell verify.js to not submit the form.
        return false; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply now my question is how can we distinguish which form is submitted? Can we pass it of the form here?

Comment: @user1951608 The first argument (`form`) to the `beforeSubmit` callback should be a reference to the `<form>` element that's being submitted.

Comment: dear my form id is form-basic so tell me i can pass the id at the place of form?

Comment: i have more than 5 forms in site but only one have ajax request so how can i use this?

Comment: i'm using that console.log($(form).attr('id')); and it will return undefined.

Comment: @user1951608 That means your `<form>` does not have `id="..."` defined

Comment: i just want to say i have 5 forms in my web site. i just want to submit one form through ajax only and on that form i just want to apply validation of verify.js. Thanks

Comment: no my form has id="login" which is unique in my whole site

Comment: <form role="form" method="post" id="login" action="auth/login" > here is form you can check this

Comment: @user1951608 Hmm, try using  `$('#login').verify({...})` instead of `$.verify({...})`.

Comment: Dear i'm really really thankful for you. You have done a great job for me thanks sir. it works yahooooooooooooooo!

Answer (score 0):

Complete example

```
<form id="formulario1" name="formulario1" action="destiny.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="field" id="field" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" data-validate="required">
<input type="submit" onclick="function_validate_form()">      


</form>
<script>
function function_validate_form(){
    $('#formulario1').verify({
    'beforeSubmit': function(form, result) {
    if (result) {
        // Since the form is valid, submit form via AJAX.
      alert('OK, send ajax');

      var formData = $("#formulario1").serializeArray();
          var URL = $("#formulario1").attr("action");
          $.post(URL,
              formData,
              function(data)
              {
                 console.log(data);

              },"json")

              .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
              {
                alert( "error ajax" );

              });


    }else{
        //do nothing
    }

    // Form is either invalid or was already submitted, return `false` to tell verify.js to not submit the form.
    return false; 
}
});
}
</script>
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="plugins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="plugins/verify.notify.min.js"></script>
```